# Zend_Search_Lucene implementation with Symfony2 returning empty result

Tags: symfony, zend-search-lucene

I have an implementation of Zend_Search_Lucene within a Symfony2 application. I am using Zend 1.11. The index seems to be being created, I have several files including:

```
_0.cfs
optimization.lock.file
read-lock-processing.lock.file
read.lock.file
segments_2
segments.gen
write.lock.file
```

here is the php code which I have inside a controller

```
$index = \Zend_Search_Lucene::create(__DIR__.'/../../../../data/index');
$doc = new \Zend_Search_Lucene_Document();
$doc->addField(\Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::unIndexed('title', 'Symfony2') );
$doc->addField(\Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('contents', 'cat dog') );
$index->addDocument($doc);
$index = \Zend_Search_Lucene::open(__DIR__.'/../../../../data/index');
$term  = new \Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term("dog");
$query = new \Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($term);
$results  = $index->find($query);
try {
    $results = $index->find($query);
}
catch (\Zend_Search_Lucene_Exception $ex) {
    $results = array();
    var_dump($ex);
}
foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    echo $result->score, ' :: ', $result->title, "n";
}
var_dump($results);
exit;
```

When I run the script the index files are created but only an empty array gets returned and is printed out with the last var_dump as

```
array(0) { }
```

Firstly does anyone know how I can check the index is being written correctly?
Secondly does anyone know why my query is not returning any results?
Has anyone successfully implemented Zend_Search_Lucene with Symfony2? I have tried both Lidaa Search and EWZ bundles but neither seems to work.

I worked all day yesterday trying to resolve this problem with no joy, so any help would be very greatly appreciated.

---

ok, so I've managed to write to the index file now by encoding as utf-8 like this

```
$doc->addField(\Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('contents', 'dog', 'utf-8') );
```

However, I can still not retrieve any results. I think it might have something to do with the locale settings but I have explicitly set this like so:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_UK.utf-8');
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'en-UK');
```

Also if I try and parse the query string as utf-8 the script hangs and timesout

```
$queryStr = $_GET['query'];
$query = \Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse($queryStr, 'utf-8');
```

Anyone know why this won't work on my Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Yeehaa! I reinstalled MAMP to version 2.0.3 and Boom! it works. I have a feeling this was something to do with either the default locale or encoding but not sure what. If anyone know why version 2.0 MAMP had a bug please let us know.

Cheers
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a commit.

```
$doc->addField(\Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::text('contents', 'cat dog') );
$index->addDocument($doc);

$index->commit(); //Try adding this line

$index = \Zend_Search_Lucene::open(__DIR__.'/../../../../data/index');
```

Comment: I've tried adding `$index->commit();` and it has no affect. According to the docs: "Newly added documents are immediately searchable in the index." Therefore `$index->addDocument($doc);` commits to the index. I think the error must be in getting the results back from the index, although does anyone know how to check an index has been created successfully?

Comment: I saw that note too (about being immediately created). I copied and ran your code and got the same result as you - adding in commit() fixed it for me. You could create a standalone PHP script to check the index, but I imagine you will get the same result.

Comment: Please could you paste a complete code example? I have tried with `$index->commit();` and it doesn't work for me. I am using Zend 1.11. What does the contents of your .cfs look like when it is created? I have also tried in a Zend application and this also does not work for me.

Comment: Also I don't know if this is related but if I try `$index->find('dog');` then the script timesout. So it seems the query is not being converted.

Comment: I have just found the answer to my own Question, Almost. Zend_Search_Lucene is not working properly on my local Mac OS 10.6.8, using MAMP. However, it does work when I put it on the Live LAMP box. So now the question is why does it not work on my local Mac environment?

Comment: tested on my Mac 10.6.8 (native php, not MAMP) with and without utf-8 and it always works. Also, removing commit() prevents the index from being written (or the results from being found). Finally, I compared the files that were written - I have all the same files as you mentioned above if I don't do a commit. With commit, _0.sti appears...